# how reduce the following elliptic equation to form of $v_{xx}+v_{yy}+cv=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

how reduce the elliptic  equation  $$u_{xx}+3u_{yy}-2u_{x}+24u_{y}+5u=0$$ to the form $$v_{xx}+v_{yy}+cv=0$$ by change of dependent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we scale a function $u$'s value by $e^{ax}$, then:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = a^2e^{ax}u + 2ae^{ax}u_x + e^{ax}u_{xx}.
$$
Hence multiplying the equation by $e^{-x+4y}$, you could check the equation can be written as:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}(e^{-x+4y}u) + 3\frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}(e^{-x+4y}u) -44 e^{-x+4y}u= 0
$$
Let
$$w = e^{-x+4y}u$$
we then have:
$$
w_{xx} + 3w_{yy} - 44 w = 0
$$

Now if we scale $w$'s variable $y$ by $b$, i.e., letting $v(x,y) = w(x,by)$, then:
$$
v_y = \frac{\partial w(x,by)}{\partial (by)} \frac{d(by)}{dy} = bw_y
$$
and
$$
v_{yy} = b^2 w_{yy}
$$
Notice $w_y$ is taking derivative with respect to $y$, while $w_y$ is rather taking derivative with respect to the second variable, if to avoid any confusion.

Therefore, we could try letting
$$
v = w(x,\sqrt{3}y) = e^{-x+4\sqrt{3}y}u(x,\sqrt{3}y)
$$
and the rest is left for you to check.